# Displaying selected items of listbox into a message box in C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, listbox, checkboxlist

**I am able to display multiple selected items from a listbox into a text box on a button click but how can I display the same on a message box? I mean displaying first item on a messagebox is not an issue but multiple items at once is. Suggestions please...**

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{

    Skill = checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(Skill);
    }
    else
    {
        listBox1.Items.Remove(Skill);
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You have selected following Skills : \n"+Skill, "Selected Skills",
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not show where `Skill` is defined, but presumably as a property of the class.  You only initialize `Skill` in `checkedListBox1_ItemCheck`.  If the selection has changed, that value will be stale (it will not reflect reality).

The shortest change to your code would be to not use `Skill` in your button handler, but rather grab the current state from the listbox (possibly put it in a local variable if you prefer that style).

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedSkills = checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show("You have selected following Skills : \n"+selectedSkills, "Selected Skills",
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are overwriting `Skill` with the last value to be checked.  So, I would expect the message box to always show the `Skill` related to the last item that you clicked on.  So, if you want to display all of them, you'll need to replace `Skill` in the `MessageBox.Show` call with something like `listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().Aggregate((o, n) => o.ToString() + "," + n.ToString())`

*Note: replace `Cast<string>` with whatever type of object `Skill` is.

Such as:

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    Skill = checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

    if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(Skill);
    }
    else
    {
        listBox1.Items.Remove(Skill);
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You have selected following Skills : \n"+ listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().Aggregate((o, n) => o.ToString() + "," + n.ToString()), "Selected Skills",
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be looping through the selected items and appending them to your textbox. In order to show on message box you need to concatenate the selected items to a string variable and use it for your message.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder skills = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (object item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
    {
        skills.AppendLine(item.ToString());
    }

    MessageBox.Show("You have selected following Skills : \n" + skills.ToString(), "Selected Skills",
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

}
```